# Put a Modal inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm making a Carnival calendar for my city.

I'm using this as a basic calendar engine: https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee-calendar

For a basic Modal i'm using this: https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js

I want to be able to click on the event and put it to show some information about it: name, time and place.

```
var eventElement = $('<div class="event"><a class="' + 
    event.location + '" href="#informa"  rel="leanModal" >' + 
    event.name + "@" + event.tickets + 
    '</a></div> <div id="informa"> <p>' + 
    event.name + '</p></div>')
```

I made a test modal in the index.html and it worked, but it is not working when i try to do this.

Comment: We need to see a little bit more of code

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an element, but haven't added it to the DOM of the page.
try something like

```
$('body').append(eventElement);
```

as the next line.

Comment: I do it bellow the javascript code: $('#' + formattedDate(eventStartDate)).removeClass('no-event').append(eventElement)